# Slicing a huuuge 2D numpy ndarray - How to do this efficiently?

Tags: python, performance, numpy-ndarray, processing-efficiency, numpy-slicing

I have a numpy array of size (24, 131000). The first of these 24 columns contains an index corresponding to a number in the range [0, 25], for each of the 131000 rows. I want to slice this array to generate 26 separate arrays, each containing the data corresponding to a single index.

I've tried this as follows:

```
for index in huge_array[0]:
    new_array = huge_array[:, huge_array[0] == index]
    np.save(...) # saves each of the 26 new arrays separately
```

Problem is this takes literal hours to be done. Does anyone know of better and more efficient ways to slice this array?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [`argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html), for example:

```py
import numpy as np

# generate a "huge" array to use for my purposes
x = np.random.randn(24, 131000)

# set first row to contain indices between 0 and 25
x[0] = np.random.choice(26, size=len(x[0]))

# get unique values in first row (assuming you don't know they'll be between 0 and 25)
values = np.unique(x[0])

# loop over unique values
for value in values:
    # get indices that contain "value"
    idxs = np.argwhere(x[0] == value).flatten()

    # output required array (if you want to keep the shape, rather than
    # have a 1d array, remove the ".flatten()" 
    np.save("myfile.npy", x[1:, idxs].flatten())
```

This should be very quick. Without the saving part, i.e., just storing the new arrays happens in under a second on my machine.

Comment: Are you sure this is actually any faster than not using `argwhere`?

Comment: You're right, I've not checked, and just doing `idxs = x[0] == value` works just as well. I can do a speed check.

Comment: I've timed it and It is slightly quicker with `argwhere`. The loop (without saving to file and just adding the subarrays into a list) runs in ~30 ms with `argwhere` and ~37 ms when generating the truth array.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
for index in huge_array[0]:
```

you're iterating over the whole first row of the data. A shape of `(24, 131000)` doesn't mean you have 24 columns. It means you have 24 *rows* and *131000* columns.

This loop executes *131 thousand iterations* when it should have executed only 26. You shouldn't be looping over `huge_array[0]`. You should be looping over `range(26)`: the integers from 0 to 25, inclusive.

```
for index in range(26):
```